# Check a text for positive and negative strings (C# to objective C )

Tags: c#, objective-c, regex

I have a text string that I want to check for several conditions on it.
I have this function in C# and I would like to port it to objective C ( I am new to it )
The checking function should return true if it contains any of (1) and none of (2)

**(1)** contains any of the below:

```
keyword1
```

OR

```
keyword2 AND keyword3
```

OR

```
keyword4
```

**(2)** should not contain any of those keywords

```
keyword4
```

OR

```
keyword5
```

OR

```
keyword6
```

I have this function done in C# using LINQ:

```
  public static string ProcessText(string text, string postiveKeywords, string negativeKeywords)
        {
            //prepare the strings to lists
            var simpleTextKeywords = text.Split(' ');

            //trim any other characters
            for (int i = 0; i < simpleTextKeywords.Length; i++ )

            {
                simpleTextKeywords[i] = simpleTextKeywords[i].Trim(
                    '~','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','_','+','-','=','[',']',';','\'','\\',',','.','/','{','}',':','"','|','<','>','?');
            }

            string [] listOfKeywords;
            if ( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(postiveKeywords))
               listOfKeywords = postiveKeywords.Split(',');
            else
                listOfKeywords = new string[] { };

            string[] listOfnegativeKeywords;
            if ( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(negativeKeywords ))
                listOfnegativeKeywords = negativeKeywords.Split(',');
            else
                listOfnegativeKeywords = new string[] { };


            //parse the keywordlist
            var matches = listOfKeywords
                        .Any(OR => OR.Split('&').All(kw => simpleTextKeywords.Contains(kw)
                            && !listOfnegativeKeywords.Any(x => simpleTextKeywords.Any(y => x == y))
                            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kw)));
            if (!matches)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            //return the first match
            return listOfKeywords
                        .First(OR => OR.Split('&')
                        .All(kw => simpleTextKeywords.Contains(kw)
                            && !listOfnegativeKeywords.Any(x => simpleTextKeywords.Any(y => x == y))
                            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kw)));
        }
```

**Update:**
Below is the code so far:

```
+ (bool )ProcessText:(NSString*)text
  andPositiveKeyword:(NSString*)positiveKeywords
  andNegativeKeyword:(NSString*)negativeKeywords
{
    //split the text words
    NSMutableArray* simpleTextKeywords = [(NSArray*)[text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy];

    //trim unwanted characters
    for (int i=0; i< simpleTextKeywords.count; i++) {
        simpleTextKeywords[i] = [simpleTextKeywords[i] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[];\'\\,./{}:\"|<>?"]];
    }

    NSArray* listOfPositiveKeywords = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    if ( ![NSString stringIsNilOrEmpty:positiveKeywords])
    {
        listOfPositiveKeywords = [positiveKeywords componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    }

    NSArray* listOfNegativeKeywords = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    if ( ![NSString stringIsNilOrEmpty:negativeKeywords])
    {
        listOfNegativeKeywords = [ negativeKeywords componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    }

    BOOL matches = false;
    for (int i=0; i< listOfPositiveKeywords.count; i++) {
            //if the keyword has "&"
            //all matches should be true
            //split the &
            NSArray* andKeywords = [listOfPositiveKeywords[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
             matches = true;
            for (int j=0; j<andKeywords.count; j++) {
                if ( ![simpleTextKeywords  containsObject:andKeywords[j]] )
                {
                    matches = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        if ( matches == true )
            break;
    }

    //if there are any matches we have to check if it doesnt have any negative keyword
    if ( matches)
    {
        for ( int i =0; i < listOfNegativeKeywords.count;i++)
        {
            if ( [simpleTextKeywords containsObject:listOfNegativeKeywords[i]])
                matches = false;
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Comment: @Tarec nothing so far, I know I can do it using several arrays and loops but I am looking for a better cleaner approach.

Comment: since there is nothing equivalent to LINQ in objective c you will have to do this with at least one loop. you will have to check your text string once for every keyword and than return the result or continue with the next keyword

Comment: @Argent `containsObject:` works on `NSSet` and `NSArray` so no looping is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the lists of positive and negative keywords and text to be checked into instances of `NSSet`. Then use the `NSSet` `containsObject:` method to check for inclusion.

Use the `NSString` method `componentsSeparatedByString:` to split the text to be searched into an array of strings.

Use the `NSString` method `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` and a set created with the `NSCharacterSet` method: `characterSetWithCharactersInString:` to trim unwanted characters.

Example code for trimming:

```
NSString *trimCharacters = @"~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[];\'\\,./{}:\"|<>?";
NSCharacterSet *trimCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:trimCharacters];
NSMutableArray *simpleTextKeywords = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *item in textArray) {
    [simpleTextKeywords addObject:[item stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:trimCharacterSet]];
}
```

Comment: I converted it to NSArray I think it will give the same result. right ? Can you please check the code I posted above.

Comment: Sure. `NSSet` just has an added benefit that there will not be multiple occurrences of an item but not really important to your needs.

Comment: `NSMutableArray` is not needed, `NSArray` is sufficient since you are not changing it. In any case if you create a `NSMutableArray ` the variable should also be an `NSMutableArray `.

Comment: I notice you are not trimming the text with the characters as you are in the C++.

Comment: I just added that code, I should use NSMutableArray for the simpleTextKeywords because I am modifying its items, right ?

Comment: Yes but see the code I added. You need to use `addObject:` to add an object. Adding an object with an index is a little suspect, it has cases where it can fail if the index is off.